# Xamarin Forms / ICommand Bindable property is not working on custom view

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, .net-core

I've created a custom view called HeaderTemplate. This control has an image. What am I trying to achieve, is to click on Image and perform some action using MVVM.

Please find below the xml and cs of that control.

**HeaderTemplate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="PS.Views.Templates.HeaderTemplate"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:PS.Behaviors">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout
            Padding="10"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image
                x:Name="ImageSource_2"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                Source="{Binding ImageSource2}">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="ImageSource2_Tapped" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**HeaderTemplate.xml.cs**

```
public partial class HeaderTemplate : ContentView
{
    public HeaderTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSource2Property =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageSource2), typeof(string), typeof(HeaderTemplate));

    public string ImageSource2
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ImageSource2Property);
        set => SetValue(ImageSource2Property, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSource2TapCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageSource2TapCommand),
                                typeof(ICommand),
                                typeof(HeaderTemplate),
                                null);

    public ICommand ImageSource2TapCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(ImageSource2TapCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImageSource2TapCommandProperty, value);
    }

    private void ImageSource2_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageSource2TapCommand == null) return;
        if (ImageSource2TapCommand.CanExecute(null))
        {
            ImageSource2TapCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

My Page (HolidaysView) has this custom control along with Image click/tap command.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="PS.Views.HolidaysView"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:PS.Behaviors"
    xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:PS.Views.Templates"
    xmlns:viewModelBase="clr-namespace:PS.ViewModels.Base"
    viewModelBase:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="true">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <templates:HeaderTemplate
                HeightRequest="60"
                ImageSource2="upload.png"
                ImageSource2TapCommand="{Binding NavigateToCommand}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and binded view model of this page contains the command

```
public class HolidaysViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public HolidaysViewModel()
    {
    }

    public ICommand NavigateToCommand => new Command(async () => await NavigateTo());

    private async Task NavigateTo()
    {

        await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<HolidayRequestViewModel>();
    }
}
```

It's not working. I don't know where I'm wrong.
Am I missing something?
I've researched alots on this but still I'm not able to find any solution uptill now.

Thank you!

Comment: *It is not working* is a blanket statement that does not provide much for us to work with. What is actually happening when you debug it when compared to what is expected.

Comment: Set some break points in the view model to confirm that it is actually binding to the view. If the command is not being called  chances are the view model may not be bound to the view.

Comment: I tried to debug and set breakfast points. The things that I was, `ImageSource2TapCommand` remain null.

Comment: Someone provided [another helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54499874/5233410) you should consider trying out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it work you will need to do just a couple of changes.

First, in the ContenView class file remove the `BindingContext = this;` line.

Then you will need to add `PropertyChanged` handlers to both of your BindableProperty

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSource2Property =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageSource2), 
                            typeof(string), 
                            typeof(HeaderTemplate), 
                            defaultValue: default(string), 
                            propertyChanged: OnImageSourcePropertyChanged);

public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSource2TapCommandProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
                            propertyName: nameof(ImageSource2TapCommand),
                            returnType: typeof(ICommand),
                            declaringType: typeof(HeaderTemplate),
                            defaultValue: default(ICommand), 
                            propertyChanged: OnTapCommandPropertyChanged);
```

If you can't spot the difference I am talking about these: `OnImageSourcePropertyChanged` and `OnTapCommandPropertyChanged`. The other changes in the Create method are not necessary I just added the propertyName so it's more clear.

You need to implement those two methods of course:

```
static void OnTapCommandPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    if(bindable is HeaderTemplate headerTemplate && newValue is ICommand command)
    {
        headerTemplate.ImageSource2TapCommand = command;
    }
}

static void OnImageSourcePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    if (bindable is HeaderTemplate headerTemplate && newValue is string imageSource)
    {
        headerTemplate.ImageSource_2.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageSource);
    }
}
```

With these changes you should be able to tap on your `Image` and navigate as you want.

The reason why?

Since you are Binding values on your "Main Page" to your Custom Control when the latter is first created these values are `null`, this is why you need to listen to the value changes and this is possible by adding the `onPropertyChanged` implementation on the Create methods.

There's also a very good explanation here in [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37076/data-binding-in-my-custom-control) post.

Your full class should look something similar to:

```
public partial class HeaderTemplate : ContentView
{
    public HeaderTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSource2Property =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageSource2), 
                                typeof(string), 
                                typeof(HeaderTemplate), 
                                defaultValue: default(string), 
                                propertyChanged: OnImageSourcePropertyChanged);

    public string ImageSource2
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ImageSource2Property);
        set => SetValue(ImageSource2Property, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSource2TapCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
                                propertyName: nameof(ImageSource2TapCommand),
                                returnType: typeof(ICommand),
                                declaringType: typeof(HeaderTemplate),
                                defaultValue: default(ICommand), 
                                propertyChanged: OnTapCommandPropertyChanged);


    public ICommand ImageSource2TapCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(ImageSource2TapCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImageSource2TapCommandProperty, value);
    }

    private void ImageSource2_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageSource2TapCommand == null) return;
        if (ImageSource2TapCommand.CanExecute(null))
        {
            ImageSource2TapCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }

    static void OnTapCommandPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if(bindable is HeaderTemplate headerTemplate && newValue is ICommand command)
        {
            headerTemplate.ImageSource2TapCommand = command;
        }
    }

    static void OnImageSourcePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (bindable is HeaderTemplate headerTemplate && newValue is string imageSource)
        {
            headerTemplate.ImageSource_2.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageSource);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.-

Note: Try to follow the example posted in one of the other answers to change your TapEvent with the Command property.

Comment: Hi, I tried but it's not working. `NavigateTo` function is never called. and `ImageSource2TapCommand` remain null.

Comment: if you debug and put a break point in this line `if(bindable is HeaderTemplate headerTemplate && newValue is ICommand command)` inside `OnTapCommandPropertyChanged` method, is it ever being called?

Comment: No, It's not calling.

Comment: Check on the Bindings on the `HolidaysView` making sure the `AutoWireViewModel` is actually working. Also, did you remove the `BindingContext = this` line on the `HeaderTemplate` class file constructor?

Comment: Yes, AutoWireViewModel is working fine (I've checked constructor by putting the breakpoint on view model). I also removed the `BindingContext = this` on HeaderTemplate class.

Comment: @Saadi I did a brand new project and copied the code I posted above and it's working find to me. I am not using Prism though but that should not be an issue I guess.

Comment: If I use the above code by creating a new project. It is working fine. But in my existing project, it is not working. I'm using `TinyIOC` for dependency injection and auto view model assignment to view. As per the analysis, Maybe, it's not working because of `TinyIOC`

Comment: Just a test, In this page you are having this issue remove the Autowire and in the XAML code behind set the `BindingContext` with an instance of you ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

[`TapGestureRecognizer` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer?view=xamarin-forms) has a [`Command` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.tapgesturerecognizer.command?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_TapGestureRecognizer_Command) accepting `ICommand`

I just tried it in a custom control similar to yours and is working fine.

So, for binding a `ICommand` to a `TapGestureRecognizer`, use the `Command` property, not the `Tap` event.

```
<Image
    x:Name="ImageSource_2"
    HeightRequest="50"
    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
    Source="{Binding ImageSource2}">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer 
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" 
            Command="{Binding ImageSource2TapCommand}" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Reference [Adding a tap gesture recognizer: Using ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap#using-icommand)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It didn't work for me. Did you create a custom `ContentView` and used that custom view into `ContentPage`?

Comment: Can you provide your ContentPage xaml along with view model?

Comment: @Saadi again you need to clarify what you mean by it did not work. What is actually happening when you debug the code? Without knowing that we are unable to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Source` of the `BindingContext` for the `ICommand` to your `ContentPage`.

```
MyViewCommand="{{Binding Path=BindingContext.NavigateToCommand, Source={x:Reference MyContentPage}}}"
```

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.PageWithCustomView"
             xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.Templates"
             x:Name="MyContentPage"
             >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <templates:HeaderTemplate
                HeightRequest="60"
                TemplateImageSource="upload.png"
                TemplateTapCommand="{{Binding Path=BindingContext.NavigateToCommand, Source={x:Reference MyContentPage}}}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```